# Segmentation fault: boolean expression

Tags: c, cs50

I am getting an error "Segmentation fault". I think it has to do with the isdigit(argv[i]) line but do not uderstand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//implement commandline arguments
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //convert string element in array to integer
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    //check that user input for key is no more than 2 memory spots, not a negative number and a single input
    if (argc != 2 || key < 0 || isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("useage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: %s \n", plaintext);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like C: `string argv[]`. Also I don't have the include file `cs50.h` and I don't know where to find get_string().

Comment: @MarceloRobertoJimenez `string` is defined as `char*` by cs50.

Comment: You have done `int key = atoi(argv[1]);` *before* you did `argc != 2`. Once you have dereferenced `argv[1]` there is little point in checking `argc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you do actually have a valid string passed as an argument, then `argv[1]` refers to that *entire string*. To check if the second *character* of that string is a digit, you need to further 'dereference' that string, and use: `isdigit(argv[1][1])`. Or, for the *first* character of that string, use `argc[1][0]` (or `*argv[1]`).