# CS50 Caesar (usage of asterisk)

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, cs50, dereference

I have a question regarding how to use asterisk in my code.

Initially I run `!isdigit(argv[1])` [without `*`] it showed segmentation fault. After referring to an online solution, I realise we should put `*` in `!isdigit(*argv[1])`. Can someone explain the function of `*` in the code? 
Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2 || !isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    string p = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf ("ciphertext: ");

    for ( int i=0, x=strlen(p); i<x; i++)
    {
        if (p[i]>='a' && p[i]<='z')
        {
            p[i] = (p[i] -'a'+key ) %26 +'a';
        }
        if (p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z')
        {
            p[i] = (p[i] -'A'+key ) %26 +'A';
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

Comment: Very similar to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249252/10871073) (and the answer I gave there).

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer (obscured by the "string" type which isn't part of standard c), so `*argv[1]` is a pointer indirection, the first byte of the second command-line argument passed to the program when it was run.

Comment: @AdrianMole, Thanks I read through your explanation. Lets say my argv[1] = hello, when I type `*argv[1]`, it means it will dereference the string into argv[1][0], argv[1][1]...argv[1][4] ?

Comment: `*argv[1]` will be the *single character* at `argv[1][0]`. For the second character in the string, which is `argv[1][1]`, you *could* use `*(argv[1] + 1)` but, in that case it's clearer to just use the two `[a][b]` format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this parameter declaration

```
string argv[]
```

the name `string` is an alias for the type `char *`.

So the parameter declaration may be rewritten like

```
char * argv[]
```

that is it is an array of pointers of the type `char *`. The compiler implicitly adjusts this declaration to `char **argv`.

So the expression `argv[1]` gives the second element of the passed to the function main array with the index 1. It has the type `char *`. The function isdigit expects an object of the type `char` converted to the type `unsigned char`. So to get an object of the type `char` (the first character of the pointed string) you have to dereference the pointer `argv[1]` having the type `char *` like *argv[1] or `argv[1][0]`.

It would be more correct to write it at least as

```
!isdigit( ( unsigned char )*argv[1] )
```

But in general this check is not enough. You should check that the whole string pointed to by the pointer `argv[1]` represents a number.

Comment: doesn't `isdigit()` expect an `int`?

Comment: More importantly, why there was a segfault in the first place. I was unable to reproduce that with a simple function such as `int isX(int c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }`

Comment: @Waqar It expects an object of the type unsigned char that used as an argument is converted to the type of the parameter.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Classification-of-Characters.html says it expects an `int`

Comment: @Waqar From the C Standard "1 The header <ctype.h> declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
characters.198) In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
representable as an unsigned char" Pay attention to words "classifying and mapping
characters." and "representable as an unsigned char".

Comment: some clarification, so it means when I type `string argv[]`, it actually compiles into `char **argv[]`. The need to include `*argv[]` so that C will check each char in the string whether it represent an int?

Comment: @Keanhong Not char **argv[] but char **argv. That is the parameter having an array incomplete type is adjusted to  pointer to its first element. So dereferencing the first time the parameter like argv[1]  you will get a pointer that points to teh first character of a string. Dereferencing it the second time like *argv[1] you will get the first character of the string. It is the same as to write argv[1][0].